# Knockout.js applyBindings with empty data model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is it possible to applyBindings when the dataModel of the viewModel is unknown? My problem is that the dataModel structure is first known after an ajax call on the page and the way i understand knockout.js is that the viewModel should be inistialized on page load?

The code fails with nCustomerId is undefined.

How should i handle this? I could wait with calling the ko.applyBindings() until i know the dataModel structure (which i do after the ajax call), but is that the right way to do it when using knockout.js?

```
function initModel () {
var kunderModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.list = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.newItem = ko.observable();  

    self.add = function () {
        self.selectedItem(newItem(self.newItem));
        showInputContainer();
    };

    self.getList = function () {
        var nButikId = jQuery("#butikid").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "crm_service.wso/Dan_Butik_Kunder_Tabel/JSON/",
            data: { nButikId: nButikId },
            success: function (data) {
                self.list(data);
            },
            complete: function () {
                connectExt.UIElements().Loading(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
}

    _viewModel = new kunderModel();
    ko.applyBindings(_viewModel);

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        initModel();
    });

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'editTmpl', data: selectedItem }"></div>

<script id="editTmpl" type="text/html">      
    <div  class="opretContainer">
        <div class="opretContainerTitle">
            <span data-bind="visible: nCustomerId == 0">New</span>
            <span data-bind="visible: nCustomerId != 0">Edit</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Just do it after the AJAX call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you do not need the **initFuction**. What you should do is initialize the **_viewModel** directly in the JQuery document callback.

You have to understand that your ViewModel itself is already a function. You can call your **getList** function directly inside your viewmodel when it is initialized.

What I would do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    _viewModel = new kunderModel();
    ko.applyBindings(_viewModel);    
});
```

and than inside kunderModel:

```
var kunderModel = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.list = ko.observableArray();

   self.getList = function () {
       var nButikId = jQuery("#butikid").val();
       jQuery.ajax({ ... });
   };

   self.getList();
}
```

This way the **getList** method gets invoked at the end of the creation of the ViewModel. (I think of it as a method which is invoked by the "constructor". Since everything is observable, when the callback is executed, your UI will be automatically updated.

Comment: thanks! also helped in understand the nature of knockout.js a bit more :)